# Maya turns screen brightness to max every time I press or hold spacebar

Tags: windows-10, display, brightness, maya

The system is Windows 10, and Maya version is 2022. Whenever I press spacebar to switch to 4-view, it briefly turns the screen brightness to max. It returns to normal after I release spacebar.
(sorry for the lack of screenshots. SuperUser is not letting me post images because I don't have enough "reputation points")

The constantly changing screen brightness is making things difficult to work with at night as the brightness will shoot up every time I switch views.
None of my other programs on this computer changes screen brightness when I press spacebar in them.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You could upload the screenshot to something like imgur.com and post a link here

Comment: Ah, we got screenshots here https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/200262/maya-turns-screen-brightness-to-max-every-time-i-press-or-hold-spacebar I edited them in your question

Comment: Same but opposite problem here https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/maya-forum/maya-2022-error-when-using-full-screen-and-pressing-spacebar-on/td-p/10190553 Have you upgraded to the latest version of Maya? It appears to be fixed in 2022.3. And it shouldn't happen if you are not in full screen.